# Delete button works random times

Tags: express

I am new to express and I was able to get most of it to work until I wanted to create a delete button.

I am having difficulty getting my delete button to work all the time. It works at random moment and other times it does not work and when it does not work the following error appears:

{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "User"

Code below:

```
Both index.js and users.js files are in routes directory
```

```js
//user - file in module directory
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser.save(callback);
      });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}
```

```html
<!--page with delete button-->
<section class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading text-center">Users Page</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          {{#each users}}
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/users/user/{{_id}}">{{this.name}}</a></li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>
</secion>
```

```js
//main.js  - file in the javascript directory
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.delete-user').on('click', function(e) {
       $target = $(e.target);
       const id = $target.attr('data-id');
       $.ajax({
          type: 'DELETE',
          url: '/users/user/'+id,
          success: function(response){
              alert('Deleting User');
              window.location.href='/users/users';
          },
          error: function(err){
              console.log(err);
          }
      });
   });
});
```

```js
//users.js - file
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../modules/user');

// Admin Page
router.get('/admin', function(req, res){
  res.render('admin');
});

// Login Page
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login');
});

// Registeration Page
router.get('/register', function(req, res){
  res.render('register');
});

// Users
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('users', {
        users: users
      });
    }
  });
});

// Individual Users
router.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, users) {
    res.render('user', {
      users: users
    });
  });
});

// Delete Users
router.delete('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  let query = {_id:req.params.id};

   User.remove(query, function(err){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }
      res.send('Success');
  });
});

// Create post request from form to server
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;
  var adminCode = req.body.adminCode;

//Validation
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is Required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
  res.render('register',{
    errors:errors
  });
} else {
  var newUser = new User({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password
  });

  if(adminCode === 'secretcode123') {
    newUser.isAdmin = true;
  }

User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(user);
});

req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

res.redirect('/users/register');

}
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown User' });
      }
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
      });
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/users/login', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();

  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

```js
//indexjs - file
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Home Page
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else {
        //req.flash('error_msg', 'You are not logged in');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

code here

can someone please advise what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like i was able to correct the error. I had to move my data-id element from from my div tag to my anchor tag: see code below:

```js
<section class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading text-center">User Page</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">{{users.name}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="btn btn-danger delete-user"/*it was here first*/><a href="#" /*now it is here*/data-id={{users._id}}>Delete</a></button>
      </div>
</secion>
```